# Disable form when loading in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, busyindicator

I have a web site designed for mobile devices. I am making ajax calls using jQuery to populate drop-downs. I am using these additional calls/methods to show a 'busy' page:

```
beforeSend: function () { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
complete: function () { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner
```

This works fine, but I want to stop any more user actions on my form (button press, drop-down change, etc) while I am showing a 'busy' page.

Probably what I want is a modal call to this.

What is the accepted norm?

Comment: what was wrong with saying 'thanks'?

Comment: what was wrong with saying diable?

Comment: `Diable` was a typo. Concerning thanks, see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/164403) on Meta.

Comment: Hi re: Diable - I know. I was joking :). Just trying to lighten this up.  Did not know about re: hi.  So thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [For mobile devices how can I temporarily prevent jQuery touch events, then reactivate them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775724/for-mobile-devices-how-can-i-temporarily-prevent-jquery-touch-events-then-react)

Comment: @Closer point taken.  I just did not see it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make div with z-index:999; width:100%;height:100%;postion:fixd;top:0;left:0
this will make any event on this div , you can add input text with postion:realtave; left:-5000px and make it focus for event keypress :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your comments. I cannot see how this will help me?

Comment: in html code write <div id="modal"></div> and in css file write #modal{display:none;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:9999;postion:fixd;}

Comment: when you wont frozen web page just call $('#modal').show() in js code